# How to call a postgres function that takes BIGINT[] as parameter from a JPA native query

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I'm trying to call a function with the following signature from a JPA native query in Java, but all attempts fail for various reasons:

signature:

```
  CREATE FUNCTION public.func_anonymize_business(business_ids BIGINT[])...
```

I have tried the following:

```
  @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM public.func_anonymize_business(?1)")
  void deactivateAndAnonymizeBusiness(List<Long> businessIds);
```

service:

```
  ArrayList<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
  ids.add(businessId);
  businessRepository.deactivateAndAnonymizeBusiness(ids);
```

This gives the error:

```
  ERROR: function public.func_anonymize_business(bigint) does not exist
```

and:

```
  @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM public.func_anonymize_business(?1)")
  void deactivateAndAnonymizeBusiness(Long[] businessId);
```

service:

```
  Long[] ids = {requesterId}; 
  businessRepository.deactivateAndAnonymizeBusiness(ids);
```

This gives the error:

```
  ERROR: function public.func_anonymize_business(bytea) does not exist
```

As well as a few other solutions, but all error out, any ideas how to call this properly? Please note I can call the function from the terminal without issue using psql.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried below:

```
private EntityManager entityManager; //Declare this in constructor
String queryString = "SELECT public.func.anonymize_business(:businessIds)";
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString);
query.setParameter("businessIds", businessIds);
Object result = query.getSingleResult();
sout(result);
```

Comment: We don't use EntityManager